# Quickly swap user agents in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extensions, user-agent

Does anyone know of a plugin or extension for Google Chrome that would allow me to quickly choose what user agent I want to appear as.

Say if I visit a site that says "Please use IE to view this page" I can just click a button instead of opening IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [User-Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aafciojnlamllgpkpdkbamkfgbofhgcj).

However, you might notice it only switches the JavaScript `navigator.userAgent` and `navigator.vendor` because apparently the Chrome Plugin API does not provide a way to modify the HTTP headers yet, but most sites only use the JavaScript variables so it should work pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many User-Agent Switchers available in Chrome Store. Now a days, you won't even need a Chrome Extension to switch the user agents in Chrome.

There are a couple of features in Chrome Dev Tools which allow you to override the user agent in Chrome.

- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/override-user-agent
- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode

There are a couple of benefits though when you use a chrome extension. That's the **Speed of Testing** with different User-Agent Strings on different websites.

Let's consider this use case, You'd like to test StackOverflow with different user-Agents

So you can configure rules in a Chrome & Firefox extension like Requestly like this

- When URL is stackoverflow.com?test1 then use User-Agent is Firefox
- When URL is stackoverflow.com?test2 then use User-Agent as iPhone
- And so on..

Here is the documentation of [Modify User-Agent Requestly Rule](https://docs.requestly.io/using-rules/user-agent-modification-rule)

Here is an example

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[IE Tab](http://bit.ly/96t4jN) For Chrome will let you do this for IE only. It gives you a button next to your address bar to quickly open the current page with an IE compatible User Agent.

Comment: Thanks, but this renders the page as IE, I just want to change the user agent to trick a website into letting me view it in chrome when its blocking me.

Comment: I do this every day on a page that blocks the use in chrome. Pages that are IE only will load in IE Tab.

Comment: Did you even try it? It doesn't just render the page differently, the user agent DOES change. Use whatsmyuseragent.com/ to see your user agent with and without the extension.

Comment: that's precisely the problem. He only wants the user agent change. He doesn't want the IE engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quickly if you make a shortcut to chrome on your desktop that points to something like this:

```
C:\Users\Saraquie\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; SAMSUNG-SGH-I777 Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"
```

Just make multiple shortcuts that all have different values for the `--user-agent=""` parameter.